# A way to test different DPI's in Unity?

Tags: unity, unity-ui

Is there a way to force a Unity canvas set to "Constant Physical Size" to scale based on an arbitrary DPI value for testing purposes? It seems to only respond to the meta-data from the display, if it has any.

Quite annoying because I'd have to use an actual device simulator to see how it will look on displays with different dpi's.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Never mind! I have since discovered the built in device simulator.

On 2020 onward you can install it through the package manager, but you have to enable "preview packages" in project settings -> package manager. After which it will be available as a toggle in the top left of the game window, or as a separate window.

On 2021 onward I believe it comes installed as standard.

Comment: Glad you resolved the issue!  Can you update your answer on how to find the built-in device simulator, please?